# Can I use Matrix Vision frame grabbers with Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, camera, matrix-vision

I am trying to aquire image using a camera connected to the Matrix Vision frame grabber in Matlab. However, when I type `imaqhwinfo`, I see the installed adaptors as 'coreco' and 'winvideo'. When I checked the device info, it says that that are no devices installed to the adaptor. The Matrix Vision frame grabber and camera has already been installed. Is it Matrix Vision is not compatible with Matlab? The camera that I'm using is Pulnix TMC-6DSP. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu need their matlab sdk http://www.matrix-vision.com/products/software/matlab.php?lang=en